# Microsoft Speech Recognition in webservices is not returning the result

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis-7, speech-recognition

Well i'm using Microsoft Speech Platform SDK 10.2.

I made a asp.Net WebService application and most of the WebServices works fine (HelloWorld(), etc...), but I have one service that uses the SpeechRecognitionEngine and when I deploy the application and try to run this webservice I get no result, i.e, I can see through the debug mode that it reaches the return line, but when I call it trought the browser the page keeps loading for ever, without any response.

Here's a sample of the code:

```
[WebMethod]

public bool voiceRecognition() {     
   SpeechRecognitionEngine sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-PT"));
   Choices c = new Choices();
   c.Add("test");
   GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
   gb.Append(c);
   Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);
   sre.LoadGrammar(g);
   sre.InitialSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

   //// just for Testing
   RecognitionResult result = null;

   if (result != null) {
      return true;
   } else {
      return false;
   }
}
```

Note: I'm using IIS to deploy the WebService Application.

If someone have some thoughts please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've found your answer or not.  When trying to solve this myself a couple of days ago, I stumbled across your question and it matched our circumstances to a "T".

In order to fix it all we had to do was put...

```
sre.RecognizeAsyncStop();
sre.Dispose();
```

where "sre" is your SpeechRecognitionEngine variable.  If you don't stop it and dispose of it at the end of your web service then the web service won't return.

Hope this helps. :)